# woo_breadcrumbs function and custom-post-type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, breadcrumbs, woothemes

I am using the woo_breadcrumbs function and need to insert the name of the curent custom post type. Currently it is showing the home page + category, `Home -> Category` . Is there a simple way to call the name of the current Custom-Post-Type and insert it between home and category? The function inside the `admin-fuction.php` file in functions folder.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found the following, hope it helps. This is written to be specific to a single taxonomy:

```
add_filter( 'woo_breadcrumbs_args', 'woo_video_filter_breadcrumbs_args', 10 );

if ( ! function_exists( 'woo_video_filter_breadcrumbs_args' ) ) {
    function woo_video_filter_breadcrumbs_args( $args ) {
        $args['singular_video_taxonomy'] = 'videos';
        return $args;
    }
}
```